# How to remove HTML Code with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In this example, content object has html code that i dont want to save. How can i save content object in this json file as a text? I would like to save in documentdb with node.js.

```
{
      "title": "Azure IoT Suite adds device management capability updates",
      "content": "<p>While the most successful enterprise IoT solutions include a strategy for operators to handle ongoing management of device collection in a simple and reliable manner, it can be a hurdle for companies getting started with IoT. To help with that challenge, we recently <a href=\"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enhancements-abound-in-general-availability-of-azure-iot-hub-device-management/\">introduced</a> device management capabilities in Azure IoT Hub.</p> <p>Today, we&rsquo;ve added these device management features to the <a href=\"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-iot-suite-connecting-your-things-to-the-cloud/\">Azure IoT Suite</a> remote monitoring preconfigured solution. The Azure IoT Suite simplifies deploying and orchestrating advanced services to give businesses a complete IoT solution from proof of concept to broader deployment.</p> <p>With new device management functionality in Azure IoT Suite, developers will be able to quickly move beyond telemetry processing, rule management, and visualization to customize their device overview, queries and device lists. These enhancements include:</p> <ul> <li>Synchronizing settings and metadata between the cloud and devices using <strong>device twins</strong>.</li> <li>Performing an action on a connected device through the cloud using <strong>direct methods</strong>.</li> <li>Broadcasting and orchestrating operations on multiple devices at a planned time through <strong>jobs</strong>.</li> <li>Attesting the status and health for on or offline device collections using real-time, dynamic <strong>queries</strong> across device twins and jobs.</li> </ul> <p><a href=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/2eff2e8f-2e3c-47d0-a504-f3482a1f87ef.png\"><img alt=\"Contoso MD-1 Devices\" border=\"0\" height=\"134\" src=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/f007d7e1-909d-4831-af81-f5f12ce33ef6.png\" style=\"border-width: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; float: none; display: block; background-image: none;\" title=\"Contoso MD-1 Devices\" width=\"480\"></a></p> <ul> <li>Customizing device information overview by using <strong>Column Editor</strong> to provide a dynamic report for devices you want to monitor right now.</li> </ul> <p><a href=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/a8e182e4-e16d-42ad-8e0b-2791e121e096.png\"><img alt=\"Costoso MD-1 Devices Edit Columns\" border=\"0\" height=\"239\" src=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/a7ce0f2b-d1c2-4afb-a9e5-25d2f7bcd55f.png\" style=\"border-image: none; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; float: none; display: block; background-image: none;\" title=\"Costoso MD-1 Devices Edit Columns\" width=\"480\"></a></p> <p>The Azure IoT Suite remote monitoring preconfigured solution is also <a href=\"https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring\">open source</a>, which gives developers the flexibility to customize it to their needs as the business evolves. We are excited to see developers achieve even more through the new device management features.</p> <p>Learn more about today&rsquo;s enhancements by reviewing our two step-by-step guides: <a href=\"https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-getstarted-preconfigured-solutions\">Get started with the preconfigured solutions</a> and <a href=\"https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-remote-monitoring-sample-walkthrough\">Remote monitoring preconfigured solution walkthrough</a>. You can also provision your IoT solution with your Azure subscription today by visiting <a href=\"http://www.azureiotsuite.com/\">www.azureiotsuite.com</a>.</p>",
      "published": "2017-02-28T11:00:06.000Z",
      "author": "Sam George",
      "link": "https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/azure-iot-suite-adds-device-management-capability-updates/",
      "feed": {
        "source": "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/feed/",
        "link": "https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/",
        "name": "Microsoft Azure Blog"
      },
      "id": "ae8e3449-7d07-bd0b-1156-43cfe4a0a75a"
    }
```

With this code i can get rid of html tags, but there are so many html code like "we&rsquo".

```
articles.forEach(function (element) {

        element.content = element.content.replace(/<{1}[^<>]{1,}>{1}/g," ");

    });
```

Is there any way to save this content without html code and tags?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: Not quite sure as to why you would try to do this on the client-side of things. I think most server-side languages have automated functions for this (such as [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) in PHP). Also, what have you tried, where did it fail, what did you expect and what is your current code? Have you read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?

Comment: I would like to save in documentdb with node.js. My collega has asked to me if i html could parse and save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an element, set the html to the content, and set the content to the resulting innerText:

```
articles.forEach(v => {
  let tmp = document.createElement('div');
  tmp.innerHTML = v.content;
  v.content = tmp.innerText;
});
```

```js
var articles = [{
      "title": "Azure IoT Suite adds device management capability updates",
      "content": "<p>While the most successful enterprise IoT solutions include a strategy for operators to handle ongoing management of device collection in a simple and reliable manner, it can be a hurdle for companies getting started with IoT. To help with that challenge, we recently <a href=\"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/enhancements-abound-in-general-availability-of-azure-iot-hub-device-management/\">introduced</a> device management capabilities in Azure IoT Hub.</p> <p>Today, we&rsquo;ve added these device management features to the <a href=\"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microsoft-azure-iot-suite-connecting-your-things-to-the-cloud/\">Azure IoT Suite</a> remote monitoring preconfigured solution. The Azure IoT Suite simplifies deploying and orchestrating advanced services to give businesses a complete IoT solution from proof of concept to broader deployment.</p> <p>With new device management functionality in Azure IoT Suite, developers will be able to quickly move beyond telemetry processing, rule management, and visualization to customize their device overview, queries and device lists. These enhancements include:</p> <ul> <li>Synchronizing settings and metadata between the cloud and devices using <strong>device twins</strong>.</li> <li>Performing an action on a connected device through the cloud using <strong>direct methods</strong>.</li> <li>Broadcasting and orchestrating operations on multiple devices at a planned time through <strong>jobs</strong>.</li> <li>Attesting the status and health for on or offline device collections using real-time, dynamic <strong>queries</strong> across device twins and jobs.</li> </ul> <p><a href=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/2eff2e8f-2e3c-47d0-a504-f3482a1f87ef.png\"><img alt=\"Contoso MD-1 Devices\" border=\"0\" height=\"134\" src=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/f007d7e1-909d-4831-af81-f5f12ce33ef6.png\" style=\"border-width: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; float: none; display: block; background-image: none;\" title=\"Contoso MD-1 Devices\" width=\"480\"></a></p> <ul> <li>Customizing device information overview by using <strong>Column Editor</strong> to provide a dynamic report for devices you want to monitor right now.</li> </ul> <p><a href=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/a8e182e4-e16d-42ad-8e0b-2791e121e096.png\"><img alt=\"Costoso MD-1 Devices Edit Columns\" border=\"0\" height=\"239\" src=\"https://azurecomcdn.azureedge.net/mediahandler/acomblog/media/Default/blog/a7ce0f2b-d1c2-4afb-a9e5-25d2f7bcd55f.png\" style=\"border-image: none; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; float: none; display: block; background-image: none;\" title=\"Costoso MD-1 Devices Edit Columns\" width=\"480\"></a></p> <p>The Azure IoT Suite remote monitoring preconfigured solution is also <a href=\"https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring\">open source</a>, which gives developers the flexibility to customize it to their needs as the business evolves. We are excited to see developers achieve even more through the new device management features.</p> <p>Learn more about today&rsquo;s enhancements by reviewing our two step-by-step guides: <a href=\"https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-getstarted-preconfigured-solutions\">Get started with the preconfigured solutions</a> and <a href=\"https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-suite/iot-suite-remote-monitoring-sample-walkthrough\">Remote monitoring preconfigured solution walkthrough</a>. You can also provision your IoT solution with your Azure subscription today by visiting <a href=\"http://www.azureiotsuite.com/\">www.azureiotsuite.com</a>.</p>",
      "published": "2017-02-28T11:00:06.000Z",
      "author": "Sam George",
      "link": "https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/azure-iot-suite-adds-device-management-capability-updates/",
      "feed": {
        "source": "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/feed/",
        "link": "https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/",
        "name": "Microsoft Azure Blog"
      },
      "id": "ae8e3449-7d07-bd0b-1156-43cfe4a0a75a"
    }];
    
articles.forEach(v => {
  let tmp = document.createElement('div');
  tmp.innerHTML = v.content;
  v.content = tmp.innerText;
});

console.log(articles);
```

Used in node.js, you can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio):

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
articles.forEach(v => {
    v.content = cheerio.load(v.content).text();
});

console.log(articles);
```

Comment: Hi @baao this give error in node.js. Should i install any package? It says ReferenceError: document is not defined.

Comment: You should have specified in your question that you want to use this in node rather than in the browser. @AttilaAlan You can try it with cheerio in node: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Comment: Edited my answer with code for cheerio @AttilaAlan